# SpecFlow+ Runner parallelization on class level

Tags: specflow, runner, specrun, parallel-execution

I want to run tests in parallel on class/feature level, my tests are running on scenario/method level, tried to change settings in srprofile, but didn't help.
I tried the same project with MSTest runner and works fine, can't figure out what to do with SpecRun.

What I want is `[assembly: Parallelize(Scope = ExecutionScope.ClassLevel, Workers = 5)]` for SpecRun

Here are my srprofile settings

```
<Execution stopAfterFailures="0" retryFor="None" retryCount="0" testThreadCount="5" testSchedulingMode="Adaptive" />
  <Environment testThreadIsolation="AppDomain" apartmentState="Unknown" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run tests parallelly on Feature/Class level using SpecRunner.
Feature parallel test execution is supported by:

- NUnit
- MsTest
- xUnit

source:
[SpecFlow Documentation](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Parallel-Execution.html)